# Regex for cpanel email filtering of .co domains without matching .co.uk

Tags: regex, cpanel

I'm getting a lot of spam from addresses with the suffix **.co** so figured a quick cpanel email filter using regex would do the job, but my regex isnt great and it matches **.co** and anything that starts with **.co** including **.co.uk** etc..

How can i make it stop matching at the **o** of **.co**

This is what i used: **(?i).co.*?**

Thanks.

(Just for context, i am using the cpanel email filter setting 'From' 'matches regex')

Comment: So you only want to match emails with `.co` and not emails with `.co.uk`, `.co.in`, etc?

Comment: yes, emails that end in .co disregarding all emails that contain .co such as .co.uk .co.etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target emails with `.co` but not with `.co.uk`, `.co.in`, etc like this:

```
(?i).co$
```

Check [this link](https://regex101.com/r/NC9iYf/1) for a practical example of the above Regex.

Comment: Thanks, thats just what i meant. I just didnt remember the $